# QRegExp and Null Character in Qt

Tags: qt, qregexp

i want search in a binary file with regular expression.
my search is successful in Text files, but not match in binary file, because QRegExp in function indexIn stop search when meet the NULL Character (chr(0)).
what can i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QString` *can* contain null characters, it's just its constructors that are inconsistent...

`QString::fromUtf8(const char *str, int size = -1)` uses the given size, while `QString::fromUtf8(const QByteArray &str)` forces a strlen instead of using the bytearray size. See for yourself [Qt code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qstring.h.html#_ZN7QString8fromUtf8EPKci).

`QRegExp` also supports null characters:

```
QString s(QChar(0));
QRegExp re(s);
qDebug() << re.indexIn(s); // will print 0, not -1
```

Comment: But don't use `fromUtf8`, it changes representation of all bytes larger than 127. There should be another encoding function. `fromLatin1` for example.

Comment: Oops, you're definitely right, I focussed too much on the null char issue and forgot the rest of bytes.